# Array.filter() to remove duplicate Ojects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to fuse `Array.filter()` function to remove duplicate objects 
I am able to achieve in the case of string or integer arrays. But I am not able to achieve the same with array of objects as in the second case of `names`

```
const names = ['John', 'Paul', 'George', 'Ringo', 'John'];
let x = names => names.filter((v, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(v) === i);
console.log(x(names)); //[ 'John', 'Paul', 'George', 'Ringo' ]


const names = [
{ name: "John" },
{ name: "Paul" },
{ name: "George" },
{ name: "Ringo" },
{ name: "John" } ];
// returns the same original array
```

Could you please help?

Comment: instead of using `indexOf` try using `findIndex`

Comment: Objects are always unique, so the first `{ name: "John" }` and the last `{ name: "John" }` are not the same object. If you only have simple objects ( objects not containing values that are objects themselves, you can use JSON.stringify() to compare two objects with eachother inside the filter function.

Comment: @Shilly JSON.stringify is not sufficient because the order of object keys is not guaranteed.

Comment: Not sure why everyone is avoiding the findIndex :), as this is the nearest equivalent of what the OP is doing.  eg.  `names.filter((v, i, arr) => arr.findIndex(v => v.name === arr[i].name) !== i);`

Comment: @GeorgeJempty The order of object keys is Never guaranteed,. as according to the spec. Although they are in most browsers these days, if the order of object keys matters, you have to use something else than an object.

Comment: @Keith I avoid the findIndex because that means you have to loop the source array for every element. If you use the memoisation technique, you only loop once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

Iterate over the `array` and create an `object` with `key` as `name` and `value` as `object` from array. In case of `objects` with same name, the `value` will be overwritten in resultant object. Finally use `Object.values` to collect all the unique `objects`.

```js
const names = [{ name: "John" },{ name: "Paul" },{ name: "George" },{ name: "Ringo" },{ name: "John" } ];

let result = Object.values(names.reduce((a,c) => Object.assign(a, {[c.name]:c}),{}));
console.log(result);
```

For tweaking - [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4TAWgZj1dE4ZGAnZESRI?p=preview)

Answer (score 4):

Using `Array#reduce()` and a `Map` accumulator then spread the `values()` of the Map into array

```js
const names = [
{ name: "John" },
{ name: "Paul" },
{ name: "George" },
{ name: "Ringo" },
{ name: "John" } ];

const unique = [... names.reduce((a,c)=>(a.set(c.name,c)),new Map).values()]

console.log(unique)
```

Comment: This is probably the best solution but please make it readable !

Comment: @PanosK that seems like a subjective thing. Is quite readable to me

Comment: I like to understand why this is the best solution compared to `Object.assign()` Is there a performance gain with this one?

Comment: @TheepanThevathasasn is purely subjective. My solution is just another of many ways to arrive at same result

Answer (score 1):

```js
const names = [
  { name: "John" },
  { name: "Paul" },
  { name: "George" },
  { name: "Ringo" },
  { name: "John" }
];
/*  unique          => Filter: Remove all duplicate items from an array. Works with plain objects as well, since we stringify each array item.
*   @type           public Function
*   @name           unique
*   @return         Function( item )
*   @notes          
*/
const unique = () => {
    const seen = {};
    return item => {
        const json = JSON.stringify( item );
        return seen.hasOwnProperty( json )
            ? false
            : ( seen[ json ] = true );
    };
};
const result = names.filter( unique() );
console.log( result );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use lodash's [_uniqBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#uniqBy) for this:

```
const names = [
{ name: "John" },
{ name: "Paul" },
{ name: "George" },
{ name: "Ringo" },
{ name: "John" } ];

const result = _uniqBy(names, 'name');
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the help of [Sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) as well

```js
var names = [{ name: "John" },{ name: "Paul" },{ name: "George" },{ name: "Ringo" },{ name: "John" } ];

var result = Array.from(
                         names.reduce((s, d) => s.add(d.name), new Set)
                         , d => ({ name: d })
                       )

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Keith had a great suggestion to use `findIndex` with `filter` instead of `indexOf`.  Object literals are always unique references, so we cannot compare them.  We can however compare the `name` keys between the objects.  We can do this with the aforementioned functions.

```
const names = [
  { name: "John" },
  { name: "Paul" },
  { name: "George" },
  { name: "Ringo" },
  { name: "John" }
];
console.log(names.filter(({name1}, i, a) => {
  return i == a.findIndex(({name2}) => {
    return name1 == name2;
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const names = ['John', 'Paul', 'George', 'Ringo', 'John'];
function removeDups(names) {
let unique = {};
names.forEach(function(i) {
if(!unique[i]) {
  unique[i] = true;
}
});
return Object.keys(unique);
}
removeDups(names); //'John', 'Paul', 'George', 'Ringo'
```